# Is it possible to define a Maven 3 profile (and its activation policy) in one place and reuse it later?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-profiles

My build process is very complex and I need to perform a few actions when running in Windows and a few in Linux, and those actions need to be placed in many different POMs.

I know I can activate a certain profile according to the OS. But all examples I find include taking action inside the `<profiles> ... </profiles>` tags, which also include the activation criteria for those profiles. What I'm trying to avoid is having to declare many sections like this:

POM 1:

```
</profiles>
<profile>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>Windows</family>
      <arch>x86</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <build>
     ...
  </build> 
</profile>
...
</profiles>
```

Then the same when I need to do something for windows in a different POM, many times all over the place... For some profiles the activation is more extensive.

I wanted to define the activation policy in one place, then do something like:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>

      <!-- if profile A is active -->
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>

      <!-- if profile B is active -->
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>

  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just configuring the plugin differently according to the active profile, without having to duplicate the plugin declaration and everything for each profile in a ton of POM files...

Also, how do I configure things in multiple places if profile A is active? Would I have to declare the  tag in each POM with its activation policy all over again or is there a way to avoid all this duplication?

Any help is appreciated, I'm a bit confused and surprised how hard is to find anything beyond basic examples on the net.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your global build for various profile in [super-pom](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) and inherit it in all the pom

Comment: I don't think this will help me because my build has 100+ POM files which use different technologies, such as Tycho for 3 eclipse-based products, plus a war file for a website and antrun for continuous integration deployment.. I can't define it all in one place. But that's the idea, define the profile activation in one place (say, super-pom or my root parent POM), and then just say "if A is active, configure plugin this way, else if B is active, configure some other way"... without having to duplicate everything, from profile definition to plugin declaration, etc